# How can I restrict Google Scholar searches to one specific journal?

Tags: google-scholar

Sometimes when I search in Google Scholar, for articles in a particular journal, I get results from other journals.  For instance, when I was searching for articles in *Psychological Bulletin*, it would also give me *Polish Psychological Bulletin*. Or an even more annoying one is when I limit search to *Science*, I get every journal that has the word "science" in it, for instance, *Psychological Science*:

[image: Search results example]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hi, yeah I do that already.  Maybe this picture will clear up what I'm saying: pixhost.org/show/255/52896991_untidsdtled.png

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting.  Btw, thanks for your edits pnuts!

Comment: You can weed out some journals using the minus ("-") operator in the journal field.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `source:"JOURNAL NAME"`.

Example: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=source:%22Psychological%20Bulletin%22